# Shared file for Kotlin DSL Android Libraries

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, dsl, android-library

For our multi-module Android project we use Kotlin DSL for our project build.gradle.kts, application module build.gradle.kts, settings.gradle.kts. However we wanted to covert our library module .gradle files to Kotlin DSL. The issue we are running into is that we get an `Unresolved reference: android` when applying the script.

I don't see any clear example on having a shared gradle.kts file for Android libaries that can be applied to Android library modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways of going about it, one more complicate than the other.

Gradle scripts use dynamic resolution, thats why you can place them in any directory and then apply them to your build file.

There are two ways to fix the issue, both involve the buildSrc/ directory.

1. You could use `kotlin-dsl-precompiled-script-plugins`.

> A precompiled script plugin is a Kotlin script compiled as part of a
> regular Kotlin source-set and distributed in the usual way, as java
> class files packaged in some library, meant to be consumed as a binary
> Gradle plugin.

https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/tree/master/samples/precompiled-script-plugin

1. You could create a custom Gradle Plugin which configures a Project.

[Here](https://proandroiddev.com/sharing-build-logic-with-kotlin-dsl-203274f73013) is a great example with a bit more details and an [example](https://github.com/chiragkunder/gradle-kotlin-dsl-sample) repo showing implementation.

Comment: Thanks this guide really helped and made it clear! I went with the pre-compiled option.